# Check image urls using python-markdown

Tags: python, markdown

On a website I'm creating I'm using [Python-Markdown](http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/) to format news posts. To avoid issues with dead links and HTTP-content-on-HTTPS-page problems I'm requiring editors to upload all images to the site and then embed them (I'm using a markdown editor which I've patched to allow easy embedding of those images using standard markdown syntax).

However, I'd like to enforce the no-external-images policy in my code.

One way would be writing a regex to extract image URLs from the markdown sourcecode or even run it through the markdown renderer and use a DOM parser to extract all `src` attributes from `img` tags.

However, I'm curious if there's some way to hook into Python-Markdown to extract all image links or execute custom code (e.g. raising an exception if the link is external) during parsing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One approach would be to intercept the `<img>` node at a lower level just after Markdown parses and constructs it:

```
import re
from markdown import Markdown
from markdown.inlinepatterns import ImagePattern, IMAGE_LINK_RE

RE_REMOTEIMG = re.compile('^(http|https):.+')

class CheckImagePattern(ImagePattern):

    def handleMatch(self, m):
        node = ImagePattern.handleMatch(self, m)
        # check 'src' to ensure it is local
        src = node.attrib.get('src')
        if src and RE_REMOTEIMG.match(src):
            print 'ILLEGAL:', m.group(9)
            # or alternately you could raise an error immediately
            # raise ValueError("illegal remote url: %s" % m.group(9))
        return node

DATA = '''
![Alt text](/path/to/img.jpg)
![Alt text](http://remote.com/path/to/img.jpg)
'''

mk = Markdown()
# patch in the customized image pattern matcher with url checking
mk.inlinePatterns['image_link'] = CheckImagePattern(IMAGE_LINK_RE, mk)
result = mk.convert(DATA)
print result
```

Output:

```
ILLEGAL: http://remote.com/path/to/img.jpg
<p><img alt="Alt text" src="/path/to/img.jpg" />
<img alt="Alt text" src="http://remote.com/path/to/img.jpg" /></p>
```

Comment: Looks really nice - sounds like +120 rep for you unless it doesn't when when testing it later. I guess I'll have to do that for both `ImagePattern` and `ImageReferencePattern`?

Comment: Looking at the fact that that it seems to be easily possible I might just completely block `image_link`, add references for the uploaded images automatically (with some prefix like `img`) and then changing the regexp so defining new references with this prefix is impossible and images only use references with this prefix. What do you think about that? Might be cleaner since I could generate the image URLs on the fly instead of having to create them initially (I need relative/absolute URLs depending on if it's in an atom feed or on the site itself anyway)

Comment: Yep, you could completely replace the regexp and the `ImagePattern` class itself to reject/ignore `image_link` if you choose. You are also correct that you'll need to also replace `ImageReferencePattern` (which I left out for brevity). I think you're on the right track - customize the class behaviors based on app-specific flags (relative / absolute, atom / site, etc).

Comment: Is there a fix for `Cannot find reference 'ImagePattern' in 'inlinepatterns.py' `?

Answer (score 1):

Updated with `Python 3` and `Python-Mardown 3`

```
import re
from markdown import Markdown
from markdown.inlinepatterns import Pattern, IMAGE_LINK_RE

RE_REMOTEIMG = re.compile('^(http|https):.+')

class CheckImagePattern(Pattern):

    def handleMatch(self, m):
        node = Pattern.handleMatch(self, m)
        # check 'src' to ensure it is local
        src = node.attrib.get('src')
        if src and RE_REMOTEIMG.match(src):
            print 'ILLEGAL:', m.group(9)
            # or alternately you could raise an error immediately
            # raise ValueError("illegal remote url: %s" % m.group(9))
        return node

DATA = '''
![Alt text](/path/to/img.jpg)
![Alt text](http://remote.com/path/to/img.jpg)
'''

mk = Markdown()
# patch in the customized image pattern matcher with url checking
mk.inlinePatterns['image_link'] = CheckImagePattern(IMAGE_LINK_RE, mk)
result = mk.convert(DATA)
print result
```

Hope it's useful!